# What is the concept behind Video Distribution Services?

Tags: php, file-upload

I came across quite a few video distribution services (one is heyspread). The video they have on their home page is like, you upload your video only once and it is distributed to other video sharing sites. To me, it looks like they have coded it in Php.

Can anyone explain me the logic behind it? How is possible? Also, will it take the bandwidth of uploading it only once or uploading it to all the sites that we are using?

Also, if I had to code one like that, are there any links which I can use as a start up to kick off?

Comment: It seems that they built their website using Ruby On Rails. Check http://builtwith.com/?http%3a%2f%2fheyspread.com%2fpage%2fabout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my explanation based on what I know and your requirements:

> Can anyone explain me the logic behind it?

You basically act as a mediator for all the sites. What the users do is given the site their permission to use their credentials that they set up in this multiple sites and allow you to upload video on their behalf so they don't have to do it themselves thereby saving them time

> How is possible?

Many of the video hosting websites operate on HTTP protocol. In order to upload on your behalf the video distribution service do the following for each of the website (I have generalize the steps, there could be more than these steps for some of the sites):

- Authenticate using the credentials that you give
- Upload the video using one of the following ways:

  - If there is API available, then this is the preferred way for the service to upload on your behalf as the interface to authenticate/upload are clean and well define
  - If no API is available for a particular website, then the service has to simulate the HTTP sequence as if the request is made from the browser by the user. This is not the best way but sometimes is the only way. This approach is not as robust as the first one because the contract could change and you don't necessarily get the confirmation message (for success/failure of upload for example) other than via parsing the HTML

> Also, will it take the bandwidth of uploading it only once or uploading it to all the sites that we are using?

It will use your bandwidth once to upload the video the first time. In order to upload to other websites on your behalf, the video distribution service will use its datacenter/cloud service bandwidth

> Also, if I had to code one like that, are there any links which I can use as a start up to kick off?

I don't know any that does exactly like that, but you should look at each site that you want to mediate and see if they have the API first. You might want to start with those who have before trying to simulate user's click for those who don't have API. For example YouTube even goes further by providing the [Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/code.html#client_libraries) for you to use based on your language of choice.